# Where to find good cave-swimming?

Tags: destinations, adventure, activities, swimming, caves

I'd love to travel to a place that has a good cave-swimming adventure.*  I'd like it to be:

- Safe
- Warm
- Fun
- Suitable for an amateur
- Good for photography is a bonus
- I'd love it if it's a cave that's connected to the ocean.
- Anywhere in the world is fine, as long as it is generally accessible to a normal tourist (no intense mountaineering training needed, etc.)

What are my options?

---

<sup>* My sister mentioned a friend took her to such a place in Hawaii, but even knowing that I have no idea how I'd find the specifics.</sup>

Comment: Just noticed this question got down-voted - I'd love to know how I can improve this question.

Comment: You could help by mentioning what part of the world you live in or have the budget to go to.

Comment: @Ankur - the question is not necessarily just to help me, so I think that's pretty open. I've added info to the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"The Grotto" on the Bruce Peninsula (Georgian Bay, Ontario, Canada) could be a good choice.  The water's always cold (though it can be plenty hot outside), but if you take appropriate precautions it should otherwise match your criteria.  It's pretty cool:

[image: picture]

You can actually swim through the hole in the bottom out into the bay.  There are a lot of cool cliffs and trails in the area, it definitely makes for a good vacation.  If you're interested in more caves and more complex caves, this might not be the place, although there are a few other bayside caves I've seen in the area and definitely more away from the water.

Comment: beautiful.. though it's creepy :)

Answer (score 8):

If you are after very safe and fun, if a bit touristy, there are several destinations around Cancun, Mexico (these are known as "cenote"). See http://yucatantoday.com/en/topics/cenotes-underwater-sinkholes.

Answer (score 4):

fun caving at Sukabumi Indonesia
Sukabumi - Indonesia

http://wisata.kompasiana.com/jalan-jalan/2010/10/19/fun-caving-di-sukabumi/

http://www.virtualtourist.com/travel/Asia/Indonesia/West_Java_Province/Sukabumi-1206389/Things_To_Do-Sukabumi-TG-C-1.html

Answer (score 4):

The [Blue Grotto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Grotto_%28Capri%29) on the island of Capri, Italy, seems to fit all your criteria:

[image]

However, it is very famous, popular and therefore overrun with tourists:

[image]

Capri is very beautiful and well worth visiting. There is also a Green Grotto on the other side of the island, which is less overrun (possibly because it's not really a fully enclosed cave).